# How to upload selected video from nougat, path returning null

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I want to upload video selecting from gallery.

I am using Intent to select video from device:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

after that:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(filePath, projection, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                    String videoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

but when i am getting path in onActivityResult() it is returning null.
I came to know that there is a change in nougat, but can't find any solution.

My code is working in all versions of android except nougat.

please anybody help.

Comment: "but when i am getting path in onActivityResult() it is returning null" -- your question does not have an `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: Dude, you have to add runtime permission for reading the videos. Please make sure you have done the same .

Comment: I have added onActivityResult() in question,

Comment: @AshishSinha I already added the permissions for read and write external storage permissions

Comment: Direct access is not allowed in nougat . check this [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

Comment: @M.Ashish I have already seen this link, but this link just telling a way to click a image from camera and save that in .provider folder and access that file.  But i  want to select a video from storage and use that path to upload video.

Comment: Dude i am talking about run time permissions

Comment: @AshishSinha yes bro, if my app is running in marshmallow it means I have all required permissions at run time. the problem is because of Nougat update

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: @M.Ashish sorry but both links are explaining same thing,  taking pics from camera.

Comment: Thats not for camera only. That is the new way of accessing file. You have to create file provider which will give you the content Uri. You can't access files directly in Nougat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  ["Android-Multipicker-Library"](https://github.com/coomar2841/android-multipicker-library) allows you to pick any kind of path in android particularly "Nougat"

Comment: Either add some code/example here OR put that as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> My code is working in all versions of android except nougat.

Not really. It might work in a couple of scenarios on a few devices.

Your code assumes that the `Uri` that you get back:

- Has the `content` scheme
- Is from a provider that will return some value for `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA` when queried on that `Uri`
- Is one where that path is to external storage, and therefore is one that you can use

None of that is necessarily true:

- On older devices, you are more likely to get a `Uri` with the `file` scheme
- Any app can implement `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for `video/*`, and they can hand back whatever they want for a `Uri`
- Providers other than `MediaStore` do not have to honor `MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA`
- The `MediaStore` indexes media on removable storage, whose paths are useless to you, as you have no read access to arbitrary locations on removable storage on Android 4.4+

To use a `content` `Uri`, call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, to get an `InputStream` on the content. Either use the `InputStream` directly, or use it to make a copy of the content to some `FileOutputStream` on a file that you control.